# Default dilation value in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

As given in the [documentation](http://pytorch.org/docs/nn.html#torch.nn.Conv2d) of PyTorch, the layer Conv2d uses a default dilation of 1. Does this mean that if I want to create a simple conv2d layer  I would have to write

```
nn.conv2d(in_channels = 3, out_channels = 64, kernel_size = 3, dilation = 0)
```

instead of simply writing

```
nn.conv2d(in_channels = 3, out_channels = 64, kernel_size = 3)
```

Or is it the case that in PyTorch *dilation = 1* means same as *dilation = 0* as given [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) in the **Dilated Convolution** section?

Comment: The illustrations here should make it obvious:
https://towardsdatascience.com/review-dilated-convolution-semantic-segmentation-9d5a5bd768f5

Answer (score 6):

From the calculation of `H_out, W_out` in the documentation of pytorch, we can know that `dilation=n` means to make a pixel (`1x1`) of kernel to be `nxn`, where the original kernel pixel is at the topleft, and the rest pixels are empty (or filled with 0).

Thus `dilation=1` is equivalent to the standard convolution with no dilation.